# Loadrunner Analysis version 2020 build 610 black screen in summary report

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

> I am using latest version 2020 build 610 of LR analysis, while
> analysing the results, getting partially black screen on the summary
> report page. have anyone face similar issue, what could be the
> possible solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to windows display resolution, if you change resolution to 1600x900 Analysis will show full screen, or you may choose font size as 100% for any resolution then it will reconfigure itself to whole page.

Comment: Thanks Suraj, its working by changing the resolution